# MySQL Workbench Over SSH ignoring MySQL Hostname setting?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I am having difficulty connecting to my RDS Database via an EC2 Instance over SSH.

Here's what happens:

1. I've configured a new Connection to go via TCP/IP over SSH 
   [image: Connection Settings]
2. When I click 'Connect' I am prompted for my password.
3. When I submit my password, I recieve an error like the following:
   [image: Error Dialog]

My Workbench appears to be trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 on the remote server, despite a MySQL hostname being specified. What could cause this to occur?

Comment: Strangely, after clicking 'Test Connection' a few times, it works, and I am able to connect. But then it stops again. I am never able to connect first time..?

Comment: Does the connection definitely work if you SSH into the EC2 instance and manually try a connection? Sounds like a bug in mysql workbench to me..

Comment: What Workbench version is that?

Comment: @MikeLischke 6.3.10 12092614 CE x64

Comment: You should definitely try the latest version 8.0.12.